# How to find only the top 3 values of a column and group the rest of the column values as zero?

Tags: sql-server

Consider a table having data as shown. I want to find the top 3 marks and combine the rest of the values of column marks as a single value 0.

```
name    age   marks   height
-----------------------------
anil     25    67       5

ashish   23    75       6

ritu     22    0        4

manish   25    0        6

kirti    23    97       5
```

**Output**

```
name    age   marks  height
-----------------------------
kirti    23    97       5

ashish   23    75       6

anil     25    67       5

OTHERS   0     0        0
```

Answer (score 5):

With TOP 3 and UNION ALL for the last row:

```
select t.* from (
  select top 3 * from tablename
  order by marks desc
) t
union all
select 'OTHERS', 0, 0, 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0f9de65a62126d8866ca91f5600ff093).
Results:

```
> name   | age | marks | height
> :----- | --: | ----: | -----:
> kirti  |  23 |    97 |      5
> ashish |  23 |    75 |      6
> anil   |  25 |    67 |      5
> OTHERS |   0 |     0 |      0
```

Comment: Why use a subquery on the first select?

Comment: Because of order by before union all. It is syntactically wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a CTE (Common Table Expression) and the ROW_NUMBER() function:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT
   [Name],
   Age,
   Marks,
   Height,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Marks DESC) AS [Rank]
FROM
   Test
)
SELECT
   [Name],
   Age,
   Marks,
   Height
FROM
   cte
WHERE
   [Rank] <= 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'OTHERS', 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking as bit too complicated... Although this works, the solution of forpas is simpler and works as well ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use select top 3 or row_number()

You can use [row_number()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as follows

```
    declare @mytable as table(name varchar(50),age int,marks int,height int)

    insert into @mytable values('anil', 25, 67, 5),('ashish', 23, 75, 6),('ritu', 22, 0, 4),('manish', 25, 0, 6),('kirti', 23, 97, 5),
    ('other',0,0,0);

    with cte as(
    select name,age,marks,height,row_number() over(partition by 1 order by marks desc) row# from @mytable )
    select name,age,marks,height from cte where row#<4 or name='other'
    order by row#
```

Another way, using union without inserting ('other',0,0,0) to the table, you can the same result

```
declare @mytable as table(name varchar(50),age int,marks int,height int)

insert into @mytable values('anil', 25, 67, 5),('ashish', 23, 75, 6),('ritu', 22, 0, 4),('manish', 25, 0, 6),('kirti', 23, 97, 5)
--,('other',0,0,0)
;


with cte as(
select name,age,marks,height,row_number() over(partition by 1 order by marks desc) row# from @mytable )
select name,age,marks,height,row# from cte where row#<4 
union select 'others',0,0,0,4
order by row#
```

[image]